# WCF client endpoint compression

Tags: c#, wcf

I am trying to implement compression for our WCF service, using a netTCP endpoint.  I've read almost all the developer network posts, and the posts on SO, to no avail.

How does one configure the client endpoint [CompressionFormat (See compression and the binary encoder)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456789.aspx)  property?  Is this in fact necessary when you've added a service reference in VS to get the generated endpoints?

I've done the standard config of the endpoint in the server app.config file:

```
<customBinding>
    <binding name="tcpCompression">
     <windowsStreamSecurity protectionLevel="None"/>
     <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip"/>
     <tcpTransport/>
    </binding>
...
</customBinding>
```

And I can make a call from the client using this endpoint.

This is the client endpoint:

Edit: I've changed the binding used on the client to implement compression on the client side as well:

```
<endpoint 
  address="net.tcp://localhost:8734/Quasar/QuasarService"
  binding="customBinding" 
  bindingConfiguration="netTcpCompression"
  contract="Quasar.IQuasarService" 
  name="CustomBinding_IQuasarService">
  <identity>
    <userPrincipalName value="foo@bar.com" />
  </identity>
</endpoint>

<customBinding>
  <binding name="netTcpCompression">
    <windowsStreamSecurity protectionLevel="None"/>
    <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat="GZip"/>
    <tcpTransport maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000"/>
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Comment: It looks like your binding needs to be wrapped in a <customBinding> tag. Have you tried this? <customBinding> <binding name="BinaryCompressionBinding"> <binaryMessageEncoding compressionFormat ="GZip"/> <tcpTransport /> </binding> </customBinding>

Comment: It looks like you are using .net < 4.5. Microsoft did not expose the compression features through the standard bindings until .net 4.5.

Comment: @sheldo: Yes, I omitted the <customBinding> tag because it is encapsulating a few other bindings, but it is there.  Thanks.

Comment: @Aron This is currently a 4.5 app, but it was started as a 4.0 service.  The only change I needed to make, AFAIK, was adding the compressionFormat attribute to the binaryMessageEncoding.

What gave this away as a 4.0 app?  At any rate, it is 4.5 now, so compression should be available, unless I am missing something else.

Comment: I've partially answered my own question: it is a matter of configuring a binding on the client endpoint.  I was under the mistaken impression that using the metadata to create a client endpoint would leverage the compression configured on the server side.  I am still working on a way to verify the compression, so, can't say for sure that the client endpoint is working correctly, but at least now I know how it is *supposed* to be enabled on the client.